# Date formatting in Karate

Tags: karate

I have the the below date returned from the SQL query in Karate feature file:

> 2020-01-31 00:00:00.0

I need to convert it to: 31-JAN-20 format. I have tried the below:

```
* def effectiveDt = 
            """
            function(s) {
      var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
      var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mon-yy");
      return return sdf.format(s)                   
            }
        """
```

but its not working for me. 
but the below worked and returns 31-00-19, but I want 31-JAN-20 format

```
var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yy");
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks , I got it working! with the below:
 var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
* def getSubtractedYear =
"""
function(s) {
  var DateTimeFormatter = Java.type("java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter");
  var LocalDate = Java.type("java.time.LocalDate");
  var ChronoUnit = Java.type("java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit");
  var dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
  try {
    var adj = LocalDate.parse('02/02/2020', dtf).minusMonths(12);
    return dtf.format(adj);
  } catch(e) {
    karate.log('*** date parse error: ', s);
  }
} 
"""
```

And call like:

```
* string subtracted = call getSubtractedYear aDate
```